# Zurb Foundation Framework [HTML/CSS] "right-off-canvas-menu" unwanted tags insertion

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I recently starting using the Foundation framework (version 5.5.0 default) and I am working with off-canvas menu's. I have been reading over the documentation for the Foundation framework for this topic here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html

The problem is that for some reason, Foundation is inserting additional tags into my markup which produce undesired results. Specifically, it generates several unwanted tags that have the form:

```
<a class="item right-off-canvas-toggle" href="#" aria-expanded="false"></a>
```

It inserts 4 separate instances of this tag throughout the page which ends up producing undesired results in my off-canvas menus.

The markup which I am using to produce this page is as follows:

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <nav class="tab-bar">
      <section class="middle tab-bar-section">
        <h1 class="title">Sample Page</h1>
      </section>

      <section class="right-small">
        <a id="toggleBottomNavBar" class="menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
      </section>
    </nav>

    <div id="bottomNavBar" class="icon-bar four-up bottom-bar">
      <a class="item left-off-canvas-toggle" href="#">
        <i class="fi-torsos-all"></i>
        <label>Contacts</label>
      </a>
      <a class="item">
        <i class="fi-comments"></i>
        <label>Chats</label>
      </a>
      <a class="item">
        <i class="fi-pencil"></i>
        <label>Compose</label>
      </a>
      <a class="item right-off-canvas-toggle" href="#">
        <i class="fi-widget"></i>
        <label>Settings</label>
    </div>

    <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
      <ul class="off-canvas-list">
        <li><label>Foundation</label></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Psychohistorians</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Encyclopedists</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Mayors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Traders</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Merchant Princes</a></li>
      </ul>
    </aside>

    <aside class="right-off-canvas-menu">
      <ul class="off-canvas-list">
        <li><label>Foundation</label></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Psychohistorians</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Encyclopedists</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Mayors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Traders</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Merchant Princes</a></li>
      </ul>
    </aside>

    <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am also using a bit of custom CSS as well:

```
.bottom-bar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.off-canvas-wrap, .inner-wrap {
    height: 100%;   
}
```

The additional tags can be seen from this screen shot while inspecting the page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJEg7.png

Would anyone be able to help me debug this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone was wondering, I have found the solution. It was a small (and embarrassing) mistake that I picked up while using an HTML validator. I neglected to close off an anchor tag on these lines:

`<a class="item right-off-canvas-toggle" href="#">
   <i class="fi-widget"></i>
   <label>Settings</label>`

The markup should be changed to the following:

`<a class="item right-off-canvas-toggle" href="#">
   <i class="fi-widget"></i>
   <label>Settings</label>
 </a>`

And the problem described is resolved.